# Library of babel floor converter code

Tags: java, converters, babeljs, floor

The Library of Babel website ([libraryofbabel.info](http://libraryofbabel.info)o) contains books with pseudorandomly generated text, each with 410 pages and located on a "floor," "wall," and "shelf" of the library. Any sequence of less than 3200 characters (including all 26 letters and the period, space, and comma) can be found inside at least one of the books.

The Library of Babel sorts the floors with some kind of base-36 (I think) number system.

The 1st floor is 0, the 2nd is 1, the 3rd is 2...
the 11th floor is a, the 12th floor is b...
the 36th floor is 00, the 37th floor is 01...
the 47th floor is 0a, the 48th floor is 0b...

And you get the idea. Anyways, I want to write Java code that takes user input for the babel floor index (e.g. 0a2) and converts it to the actual floor number.

Since I'm an ultra noob at Java, I'm lost. How on earth should I go about coding the conversion process?

EDIT:
Alright made an algorithm, wrote some code. Code not working:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Sandbox 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        System.out.println("enter babel floor:");
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = num.nextLine();
        int sum = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x<s.length(); x++)
    {
        int store = s.charAt(s.length() - x - 1);

        if(store>=10)
        store = store-86;

        else
        store+=1;

        sum += store * (int) Math.pow(36, x);
    }

    System.out.println(sum);

    }
}
```

I entered 01 which should print 38, but instead it prints 1814. I haven't tried anything else at the moment. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT 2:
I think I did it!:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Sandbox 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        System.out.println("enter babel floor:");
        Scanner num = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = num.nextLine();
        int sum = 0;

    for(int x = 0; x<s.length(); x++)
    {
        int store = s.charAt(s.length() - x - 1);

        if(store>=97)
        store = store - 86;

        else
        store = store - 47;

        sum += store * (int) Math.pow(36, x);
    }

    System.out.println(sum);

    }
}
```

EDIT 3:
Nope. Don't work. 10 should print 53 but instead I'm getting 73. Faulty algorithm I think.

EDIT 4:
Disregard EDIT 3. Code works as intended. 10 should indeed print 73, and it works for all else too.

Comment: Is there another programming language that you are more experienced in? Is the problem coming up with an algorithm, or expressing it in Java, or both? You could take some courses, read a book on algorithms and Java, or do some tutorials. Also, see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And, welcome to SO, of course!

Comment: Hi kenney. Java is my first computer language and although I took a course on it, that was a couple years ago and I don't remember everything. I could probably come up with an algorithm if I tried hard enough, so the main problem would be with expressing it in java.

Comment: Ah, allright. Well, if you post the code you have and tell us where you get stuck then we can help with specifics. I can give you a suggestion to get started: make a [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) that is 36 characters long, and use `String.indexOf`. Solve it for a 1 character user input first (`0` .. `z`).

Comment: think i figured it out

Comment: @element11 - Ermm no.  It would be better to simply delete the question!  Posting the solution is only going to put the OP at risk of a fellow student copying it!  Remember that when one student copies another student's work, there are TWO guilty parties ... as far as the disciplinary committee is concerned.

Comment: @Stephen C I'm not doing this for homework haha, it's just something I'm doing in my spare time.

Comment: @David - even so.  If you put your solution up, that doesn't really help anyone else learn.  And learning is the real point.  And in fact, I would encourage you to try to solve this >>without<< asking questions.  For example, use a debugger.

Comment: @Stephen C well, either way my solution don't work at the moment haha

Comment: Okay, so my code actually works, but I think it's okay to leave it up there because I highly doubt that any teacher would assign this particular example as a homework problem. Not many people know of the Library of Babel website, and even if someone did, it's not likely that they would use this particular example as a computer science problem.